# How to use a controller as service with @Route annotation in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

I've a controller which is configuered as a service. I'd like to use `@Route` annotations to define the route.

When I try to access the route I get:

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Galexis\RequestDispatcherBundle\Controller\RequestDispatcherController::__construct() must implement interface Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, none given, called in /Users/ugxnbpluse/development/git/integrationPHP/symfony2/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2282 and defined in /Users/ugxnbpluse/development/git/integrationPHP/symfony2/src/Galexis/RequestDispatcherBundle/Controller/RequestDispatcherController.php line 29
```

From the error message I understand, that symfony doesn't know, that it should not call new for the controller but take it from the DI container.

The [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) (last section) tell me to add something like

```
@Route(service="my_post_controller_service")
```

but it seams that symfony does not really support the service property:

```
BadMethodCallException: Unknown property 'service' on annotation 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route'.
```

Any ideas?

Controller:

```
class RequestDispatcherController
{
    // ... 

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        RequestDispatcherService $requestDispatcherService)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->requestDispatcherService = $requestDispatcherService;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("requestDispatcher/{applicationName}")
     * @return Response
     */
    public function dispatch(Request $request)
    {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

routing.yml:

```
_request_dispatcher:
    resource: "@FooRequestDispatcherBundle/Controller/RequestDispatcherController.php"
    type:     annotation
```

service.yml:

```
parameters:
    request_dispatcher.class:                 Foo\RequestDispatcherBundle\Service\RequestDispatcherService
    request_dispatcher_controller.class:      Foo\RequestDispatcherBundle\Controller\RequestDispatcherController

services:
    request_dispatcher_service:
        class:        "%request_dispatcher.class%"
        arguments:    ["@foo.integration.application", "@buzz.multi.client" ]

    request_dispatcher_controller:
        class:        "%request_dispatcher_controller.class%"
        arguments:    ["@logger", "@request_dispatcher_service"]
```

Comment: So what was the problem finally?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` instead of `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;`.